# Spark Structured Streaming checkpoint usage in production

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I have troubles understanding how checkpoints work when working with Spark Structured streaming.

I have a spark process that generates some events, which I log in an Hive table.
For those events, I receive a confirmation event in a kafka stream.

I created a new spark process that

- reads the events from the Hive log table into a DataFrame
- joins those events with the stream of confirmation events using Spark Structured Streaming
- writes the joined DataFrame to an HBase table.

I tested the code in spark-shell and it works fine, below the pseudocode (I'm using Scala).

```
val tableA = spark.table("tableA")

val startingOffset = "earliest"

val streamOfData = .readStream 
  .format("kafka") 
  .option("startingOffsets", startingOffsets)
  .option("otherOptions", otherOptions)

val joinTableAWithStreamOfData = streamOfData.join(tableA, Seq("a"), "inner")

joinTableAWithStreamOfData 
  .writeStream
  .foreach(
    writeDataToHBaseTable()
  ).start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

Now I would like to schedule this code to run periodically, e.g. every 15 minutes, and I'm struggling understanding **how to use checkpoints** here.

At every run of this code, I would like to **read from the stream only the events I haven't read yet in the previous run**, and inner join those new events with my log table, so to write only new data to the final HBase table.

I created a directory in HDFS where to store the checkpoint file.
I provided that location to the spark-submit command I use to call the spark code.

```
spark-submit --conf spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation=path_to_hdfs_checkpoint_directory 
--all_the_other_settings_and_libraries
```

At this moment the code runs fine every 15 minutes without any error, but it doesn't do anything basically since it is not dumping the new events to the HBase table.
Also the checkpoint directory is empty, while I assume some file has to be written there?

And does the readStream function need to be adapted so to start reading from the latest checkpoint?

```
val streamOfData = .readStream 
  .format("kafka") 
  .option("startingOffsets", startingOffsets) ??
  .option("otherOptions", otherOptions)
```

I'm really struggling to understand the spark documentation regarding this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you post full code or actual code which is working in scala shell ??

Comment: my guess is dataframe ```joinTableAWithStreamOfData``` is empty & because of this  writestream is not triggered or started.. if it is started, checkpoint location would have created.

Comment: Try looking at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584476/do-we-need-to-checkpoint-both-readstream-and-writestream-of-kafka-in-spark-struc

Comment: Thanks for your comments! @Rayan I saw already that answer and that triggered me to write my question :) So the checkpoint should be set when **writing** the stream somewhere? I was wondering how does that actually work, because i'm not only writing the stream to a table, but first I join the stream with other data and then i write to HBase, so I was wondering how does the checkpoint on the writeStream work

Answer (score 2):

#### Trigger

> "Now I would like to schedule this code to run periodically, e.g. every 15 minutes, and I'm struggling understanding how to use checkpoints here.

In case you want your job to be triggered every 15 minutes, you can make use of [Triggers](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers).

You do not need to "use" checkpointing specifically, but just provide a reliable (e.g. HDFS) checkpoint location, see below.

#### Checkpointing

> At every run of this code, I would like to read from the stream only the events I haven't read yet in the previous run [...]"

When reading data from Kafka in a Spark Structured Streaming application it is best to have the checkpoint location set directly in your `StreamingQuery`. Spark uses this location to create checkpoint files that keep track of your application's state and also record the offsets already read from Kafka.

When restarting the application it will check these checkpoint files to understand from where to continue to read from Kafka so it does not skip or miss any message. You do not need to set the startingOffset manually.

It is important to keep in mind that only specific changes in your application's code are allowed such that the checkpoint files can be used for secure re-starts. A good overview can be found in the Structured Streaming Programming Guide on [Recovery Semantics after Changes in a Streaming Query](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#recovery-semantics-after-changes-in-a-streaming-query).

---

Overall, for productive Spark Structured Streaming applications reading from Kafka I recommend the following structure:

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder().[...].getOrCreate()

val streamOfData = spark.readStream 
  .format("kafka") 
// option startingOffsets is only relevant for the very first time this application is running. After that, checkpoint files are being used.
  .option("startingOffsets", startingOffsets) 
  .option("otherOptions", otherOptions)
  .load()

// perform any kind of transformations on streaming DataFrames
val processedStreamOfData = streamOfData.[...]


val streamingQuery = processedStreamOfData 
  .writeStream
  .foreach(
    writeDataToHBaseTable()
  )
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/checkpoint/dir/in/hdfs/"
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("15 minutes"))
  .start()

streamingQuery.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: I'm trying to same implementation in pyspark. My concern is that I want to make sure if application is restarted then must be started from same offsets of the Kafka partitions. And I specify checkPointingLocation opstion in readStream() but it seems that does not work (according to logs it specifies another location in tmp folder). So I wonder in this model why do we specify the check point location in the writeStream(), shouldn't it be in the readStream()?

Comment: From my understanding, the checkpoint will record what offset had been processed(had been written succeed), so be in the writeStream() should be more proper.